# Make sequence autoincrement order number by variable in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

In my example I have this table :

```
| name | number   |
-------------------
| abc  |          |
| bca  |          |
| sad  |          |
| tyu  |          |
| hjh  |          |
| lpk  |          |
| ass  |          |
| drc  |          |
| dfg  |          |
```

then i get some variable filled with number like :

$order = 3, then i want to make query to update the table above to look like this :

```
| name |  number  |
--------------------
| abc  |     1    |
| bca  |     2    |
| sad  |     3    |
| tyu  |     1    |
| hjh  |     2    |
| lpk  |     3    |
| ass  |     1    |
| drc  |     2    |
| dfg  |     3    |
```

How do I do that in mysql query??

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Ok and what you tried so far?

Comment: Use modulus logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @order=3;
UPDATE Table1 SET number2=MOD(number-1,@order)+1;
```

Comment: ...which begs the question; why store this at all?

Comment: works like a charm, but what if the number filed is not relevant now. so all i need is 1 number field